# I have been attempting to install django for python 2.7, and I have run into an error message when installing setup.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Everything had been going well, I had downloaded django, extracted it, I had **django 1.8.2** as a file on my desktop, and I had created a path to my python directory. When I went into the command prompt, I navigated to the desktop, then the django file, and I now had this in the cmd:

```
C:\Users\roman_000\Desktop\django\django>python setup.py install
```

When I hit enter I was presented with a very very long error message that essentially said:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-4172.write-test'
```

It then went on to suggest that maby I dont have the write access(which I do) etc, after much frustration I am here.

Comment: well....do you  have write access?

Comment: yes i do, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Are you running cmd as administrator (relevant if you're on Windows 7 / 8)

Comment: when I do that I get this: python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: you need to 1) open command prompt as administrator 2) navigate to the `C:\Users\roman_000\Desktop\django\django` since that is where your `setup.py` file is and 3) run the `python setup.py install`